# Apache with python wsgi reaches MaxRequestWorkers and becomes unresponsive

Tags: apache-2.4, python, wsgi

I have an application running on apache under Ubuntu (tried 12 and 14) using python via WSGI. When I get a little too much traffic I see "server reached MaxRequestWorkers..." in the error log, I will of course take care of enlarging the amount of workers I support (I've read all there is about what exactly to do) but after I reach this the apache becomes unresponsive and even when there is no more load I can't get any response from it.